# Regular expressions with backreferences over unary alphabet

Tags: formal-languages, computability, regular-languages, undecidability, regular-expressions

Setting:

- regular expressions with backreferences
- unary language (1-symbol alphabet)

Is the following problem decidable in this setting:

- Given a regular expression with backreferences, does it define a regular language?

For example, `(aa+)\1` defines a regular language, while `(aa+)\1+` doesn't. Can we decide which one is the case?

---

For concreteness, "regular expressions with backreferences" here refer to e.g. the following subset of the usual [Perl-compatible regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions):

- `a` matches character `a` (the only character in the alphabet)
- `X*` matches 0 or more occurrences of `X`
- `X|Y` matches `X` or `Y`
- parentheses can be used for grouping and capturing
- `\1`. `\2`, etc. match the same string as the 1st, 2nd, etc. pair of parentheses

We can also use the normal shorthands e.g. `X+` = `XX*`.

Comment: Have you explored counting approaches, i.e. inspecting the sequence of $|L_n|$? I guess you are familiar with the work of Freydenberger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evidence against the effective decidability of the problem is provided by the construction in the proof of Theorem 9 in my paper [*On Practical Regular Expressions*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.1258v2): You could determine if there are finitely many Fermat primes.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've added a fuller citation to your paper.